# Flutter. How to continue listen GestureDetector onLongPressMoveUpdate without finger up in new screen

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I built an interface where in SliverList, when long pressing on a child element, ModalRoute opens. [from this state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUK3J.png)I want the ModalRoute to close when I release my finger, but the action is not passed to the GestureDetector in the new modal window. [to this state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jENvb.png)

I tried passing a GestureDetector and activating it programmatically, but that didn't help.